# jQuery: count of first level of li tags (exclude decendent ul > li tags)

Tags: jquery, html, count, html-lists

**HTML:**

```
<ul id='top_nav'>
  <li><a href="">xxx</a></li>
  <li><a href="">xxx</a></li>
  <li><a href="">xxx</a></li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">xxx</a></li>
      <li><a href="">xxx</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">xxx</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Question:**

How can I get the count of the first level of li tags?  So in this example, the output would be 5, not 7.

Comment: Output should be 4? Looks to me like it should be 5.

Comment: haha!  Yes, you're absolutely right!  I will edit my question.  Before: "4, not 6" | After: "5, not 7"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$("#top_nav > li").size()` should do the trick.

This works because a selector akin to `foo > bar` selects the immediate children of foo that match bar. the `size()` function returns the number of entities selected.

Comment: ah, I forgot the ">" character.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, without `>`, all the list items within `top_nav` are selected, even not direct children.

Comment: FYI for those reading this: seems like .size() is a newer (better performance) function .. but .length is supported for older versions of jQuery ... but they both behave the same

Answer (score 2):

Use some css with your query and make it even easy.  Remember, jQuery already did all the hard work so you don't have too:

```
$("ul li:first-child")
//  the previous simply is a call to all unordered list items that re first in the list
$("ul li:first-child").length
// the previous will get you the total count of all first list items
```

LOL just realized i misunderstood the question in which case the answer is already there

```
$("#top_nav > li")
```

Answer (score 1):

David and Jasper both give good options but you also have to filter the li that has a ul child to get 4 as the output:

```
$("#top_nav > li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children('ul').length == 0;
}).size()​
```

Comment: haha!  I'll edit my question.. it should have been 5, not 4.  I'll +1 you though.  Good eye, good eye!